# How to save a ppt file in databricks to my user folder?

Tags: python-3.x, databricks

I have a ppt file and want to save it to my user folder inside the databricks dbfs system. This is what I have:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Cm
import shutil

pptx.save(some_name + '.pptx')
```

Now, I found this command example but I am not sure if its going to work and how to change it to my specifications:

```
dbutils.fs.put("/FileStore/my-stuff/my-file.txt")
```

What does FileStore, and my-stuff stand for? Where do I specify my user name to map to my folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command to save the ppt file to databricks filesystem.

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"

prs.save('/dbfs/test.pptx')
```

**Sample Notebook:**

[image]

**OR**

If you want to save ppt file from local machine to Databricks filesystem, you can use Databricks cli cmdlet.

```
dbfs cp "A:AzureLearning\AzureDatabricks\BRK4024.pptx" dbfs:/myfolder/BRK4024.pptx
```

[image]

**FileStore** and **my-stuff** are the folders inside the databricks filesystem. You can create a new folder with any name and save the your files into that folder. Where in the above databricks CLI example, I have saved the "BRK4024.pptx" file in the folder named "myfolder".

**Reference:** [Getting started with python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is so great! The last step /question is how to now access this file. Would you also happen to know this?

Comment: I have responded on your new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826584/how-to-display-and-download-a-pptx-file-from-databricks/58831651#58831651

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT when I run this I get "[Errno 95] Operation not supported" - any ideas how I can get around this?