# How to display and download a pptx file from databricks?

Tags: python, windows, powerpoint, databricks

I generated a power point deck with a utility script in databricks using Python. I want to access the file now in the kernel but due to the images in the deck, it shows strange symbols. How do I correct this statement which outputs the deck image?

```
#access file
dbutils.fs.head('file:/dbfs/user/test.pptx')

Out: 'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00D�lOƯ�g�\x01\x00\x00�\x0c\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00[Content_Types].xml͗�N�0\x10��<E�K\x0e�q�\x175��rb�\x04<�I����-ϴзg�.��R�\n_\x12�3���\'Q4霼�:\x1a�GeM�l��$\x02��B�A���]�\x0e�\x08I�Bjk K&��Iw�s7q�\x11\x17\x1b��!�;\x16\x02�!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to display a pptx file from databricks?

To display a pptx file from databricks using below code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation('/dbfs/myfolder/BRK4024.pptx')
for slide in prs.slides:
  for shapes in slide.shapes:
    print( shapes.shape_type )
    print( '----------------' )
    if shapes.has_text_frame:
      print( shapes.text )
```

**Notebook sample:**

[image]

**Note:** In the output you will see ("[PlaceHolders](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/placeholders.html)", "AutoShapes", "Pictures") because **python-pptx** does not support SmartArt. You need to manually insert content into a placeholder/AutoShapes/Pictures, which will be overhead task to build in python.

**Example:** [Sample code - add an image in every Powerpoint slide using python-pptx](https://gist.github.com/glass5er/748cda36befe17fd1cb0)

> How to download a pptx file from databricks?

You can use databricks cli to download files from databricks file system to local machine as follows;

```
dbfs cp dbfs:/myfolder/BRK4024.pptx A:DataSet\
```

**Example:** Since I have a sample BRK4024.pptx file in myfolder on dbfs, I'm using databricks cli command to copy to local machine folder name (A:Dataset)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just additionally answer for the partial question `How to display a pptx file from databricks?`.

Ofcouse, I see @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT has answered for how to use `python-pptx` to extract the text content of a pptx file and show in the databricks notebook.

However, if you want to display the whole slides of a pptx file as images in the databricks notebook like the blog [`Converting presentation slides to HTML blog post with images`](https://opensourcehacker.com/2013/05/02/converting-presentation-slides-to-images-and-html-blog-post/) did, it's impossible in the databricks notebook, the reason as below.

1. Databricks is running in Linux, so you can not convert a pptx file to images via `win32` api for invoking MS PowerPoint Application.
2. The existing solution for converting pptx to images requires to install `LibraOffice` in the running machine, but I'm afraid that you can not do that on Linux OS for cloud databricks. Due to the issue https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/348, `python-pptx` can not do the conversion. Even there is not any Python package can do it alone.

If the databricks you used is a private machine, you may try to follow the SO thread [How to convert pptx files to jpg or png (for each slide) on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523267/how-to-convert-pptx-files-to-jpg-or-png-for-each-slide-on-linux) or the code from https://github.com/innaky/pptx-to-images/blob/master/pptx-to-images.py to get the images of slides of a pptx file, then you can refer to the section [`Display images`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#display-images) of the databricks docuemnt `Use Notebooks` to display them.

Sure, also you can upload images converted from a pptx file on local to cloud databricks, then to display them. But automatically to do these completely on cloud databricks seems to be impossible.